# How to use Unity Transport API properly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

i am trying to establish a network communication using Unitys transport api.

The network connection is running, both devices can send and receive broadcasts via the *NetworkDiscovery* component from eachother. So far so good.

Now if i try to send data via the Transport API i receive errors on the sending device, and nothing on the receiving side.

```
public void Send()
{
    Connection = new NetworkConnection();
    var info = LobbyRenderer.GetSelectedHostInfo();
    Connection.Initialize(info.ipv4, 1, 1, new HostTopology(new ConnectionConfig(), 1));

    byte connectionError;
    websocketId = NetworkTransport.AddWebsocketHost(new HostTopology(new ConnectionConfig(), 1), 47774);
    connectionId = NetworkTransport.Connect(websocketId, info.ipv4, 47774, 0, out connectionError);

    byte sendError;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[2] { 1,1 };
    NetworkTransport.Send(websocketId, connectionId, 1, bytes, 2, out sendError);
}
```

the connectionError byte returns 4,
the sendError byte returns 2.

Unity Console:

[image: unity console]

I'd appreciate a hint on how to make this work.

Comment: i noticed that "Not enough resources are available to process this request." is returned from NetworkTransport.Connect as error code 4. but what do i miss at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's the case but I can't see any QOS Channel in your code, try adding one, you have to provide QOS Channel when sending as well.

```
public void Send()
{
    Connection = new NetworkConnection();
    var info = LobbyRenderer.GetSelectedHostInfo();
    Connection.Initialize(info.ipv4, 1, 1, new HostTopology(new ConnectionConfig(), 1));

    byte connectionError;
    ConnectionConfig config = new ConnectionConfig();
    int myReliableChannelId  = config.AddChannel(QosType.Reliable);
    int myUnreliableChannelId = config.AddChannel(QosType.Unreliable);
    websocketId = NetworkTransport.AddWebsocketHost(new HostTopology(config, 1), 47774);
    connectionId = NetworkTransport.Connect(websocketId, info.ipv4, 47774, 0, out connectionError);

    byte sendError;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[2] { 1,1 };
    NetworkTransport.Send(websocketId, connectionId, myReliableChannelId, bytes, 2, out sendError);
}
```

Comment: i had a magic '1' there, because i didn't know what was expected... thanks! :)